# dynamically import type in typesript

Tags: typescript

I have a file say `MyFactory.ts`.  Content of the file is given below:

```
export type CommandFactory = () => string[] | undefined;
export enum FactoryIds {commandFactory : 'commandFactory'}
```

Now I want to dynamically import this file in another file (say `main.ts`) and use type `CommandFactory` in it. Content of `main.ts` is given below:

```
const Factory = await import('./MyFactory');
const commandFactories : Factory.CommandFactory[] = []; //Here I am getting error that Property 'CommandFactory' does not exist on type 'typeof import('MyFactory')'
```

While I can easily get `FactoryIds` by `Factory.FactoryIds` but not able to access `CommandFactory` using `Factory.CommandFactory`.
I wanted to know how can I dynamically import `CommandFactory` type in my `main.ts` file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no sense in dynamic importing a type since types are static – they are eliminated after compilation. If you need to import types from a module you want to import dynamically, you can import the types separatelly:

```js
import type { CommandFactory } from './MyFactory';

const Factory = await import('./MyFactory');
```

`import type` statements are eliminated during compilation, so your module will still be imported only dynamically in runtime.

Comment: I found this answer when I was trying to dynamically resolve an enum by string. While youre right about types (eliminated after compilation), enums are an exception. I was able to do `const enum = (await import("somePackkage"))?.["EnumTypeAsString"]` since enums 'survive' compilation

Comment: I believe you can actually import an enum twice, first time with `import type`, and then with dynamic import. And then use it as always, probably